# Executing a statement after a fetch request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following structure of code:

```
var cdict = new Map();

fetch("randomurl")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {

    for (const obj of data.result) {
        // insert stuff into Map cdict
    }
    counter(0).then(res => {
        console.log(cdict);
    }) 
  
  // ^ here after calling of counter i need to do stuff

});


const cbegin = 0;
const ccount = 10;

function counter(cnt) {
    if (cnt < ccount) {
        setTimeout( () => {
            cnt++;
            
            fetch(someurl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {

                for (const obj of data.result) {
                    // do stuff
                }
                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

            counter(cnt);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Here after execution of `counter(0)`  call and all its fetch requests, I wish to execute a line `console.log(cdict);`

How can this be achieved? And is this proper way to call fetch requests with delay of 1 second?

Comment: You'll likely need to look at returning a promise which yields after the delay

Comment: [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `setTimeout` event queue callbacks with promise-based code -

```js
const sleep = time =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

async function main()
{ console.log("please wait 5 seconds...")
  await sleep(5000)
  console.log("thanks for waiting")
  return "done"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Don't write `.then(res => res.json())` every time you need some JSON. Write it once and reuse it -

```js
const fetchJSON(url, options = {}) =>
  fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json())

async function main()
{ const data = await fetchJSON("path/to/data.json")
  console.log("data received", data)
  return ...
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Don't attempt to declare variables outside of Promises and modify them later. You **cannot** [return the result of an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/633183). Asynchronous data needs to stay contained within the promise or you will be chasing hard-to-find bugs in your code -

```js
async function main(urls)
{ const result = []
  for (const u of urls)           // for each url,
  { result.push(await getJSON(u)) // await fetch and append to result
    sleep(1000)                   // wait 1 second
  }
  return result
}

const myUrls =
  [ "foo/path/data.json"
  , "another/something.json"
  , "and/more/here.json"
  ]

main(urls)
  .then(result => /* counter logic */)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

Continue abstracting as you see fit -

```js
// give reusable functions a name; use parameters for configurable behaviour
async function fetchAll(urls, delay = 100)
{ const result = []
  for (const u of urls)
  { result.push(await getJSON(u))
    sleep(delay)
  }
  return result
}

async function counter(urls)
{ const results = await fetchAll(urls) // use our generic fetchAll
  const cdict = /* counter logic... */
  return cdict
}

const myUrls =
  [ "foo/path/data.json"
  , "another/something.json"
  , "and/more/here.json"
  ]

counter(urls).then(console.log, console.error)
```

As you can see `async` and `await` prevent nesting that occurs with the use of `setTimeout` or `.then` callbacks. If you use them correctly, your code remains flat and you can think about your code in a synchronous way.

Comment: this is very useful, i got to learn a lot